# About Me section looks ugly

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design, profile-page

At first: I really like the site design. It's modern and fits the purpose of the site. I just have one minor question: what do you think of the About Me section on a user's profile page?

[image]

In my opinion, there's too much contrast. Why not a light background so that the text can be dark, just like everywhere on the site? [Other](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17592/camil-staps) [sites](http://stackexchange.com/users/1679769/camil-staps) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544337/camil-staps) [a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23992/camil-staps) [light](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26607/camil-staps) [layout](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/205264/camil-staps).

I kinda relied on having a light background when I chose to use the light flair instead of the dark flair. On every other SE I checked, there is a light background. Every, but this one. That makes it hard to "Save and copy profile to all StackExchange accounts".

So, can we please have a light background with dark text?

Comment: I think the only person who can really reply to this is our designer @Jin. I'll hunt him down if he doesn't find this on its own in a few days.

Comment: @JeffFerland thanks! No hurry needed. Until then, the community can speak with voting.

Comment: 100% agreed! We need a light background with dark text. The current one is ugly. I've always assumed it's a way to annoy security experts, thus encouraging them to attack the site and attempt to change it themselves so potential vulnerabilities are discovered.

Comment: @JeffFerland do you have any information on the status of this?

Comment: @CamilStaps Just nudged the staff on it, so you should get an answer from somebody within the week.

Comment: the meta profile looks much more reasonable

Comment: Jin, our designer, has said that he shall be looking into this soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is too dark. I've updated the about box background to a very light teal color to fit with the rest of the site's color scheme. The change will be on production server after our next build. (within 24hrs or so).

Comment: Yeah, it looks very nice now! Thanks!

Comment: That's much nicer @Jin. There was much rejoicing. Yay.

Answer (score 2):

I think I agree. It's just too dark as it is - however, if you have a look at the *meta* user profile that is a lot nicer - a faint silvery background more in keeping with the design of SO, math.SE, the beta theme etc.

I'd vote for changing it to something with less contrast, although I am not entirely sure what as I am not a skilled designer and my user interfaces tend to look a little... let's not go there. Maybe one of the lighter blues from the palette?